# Can I access and read the local storage of an old iOS/Android app with a new rewritten Flutter app with the same BundleID?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, local-storage, sandbox

I have an old iOS and Android app and there users can favorite products. The favorites of a user are always stored locally on the device, but are not synchronized with the server. I have now written a new Flutter app and would like to access the favorited products of each user of the old iOS app. Is it possible, if I publish/replace the app via AppStoreConnect under the same BundleID, to access the storage of the previous app? Basically, Apple has no way of knowing if this is just an update or a complete redevelopment of the app. However, I would like to know whether I can also access the memory in such a constellation to read the keys and values of the favorite products from the local memory. Can someone tell me if this is possible without much work? Does anyone have experience with such a migration?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: sadly not. Im still looking for a solution

Comment: use this https://pub.dev/packages/native_shared_preferences for read previous shared pref (android) and nsuserdefault (ios). 
install the upgrade on the old version (not uninstall it)